# Как подогнать размер компонента Text под размер его текста Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, ui

У меня есть объект с компонентом текст на панеле, которая меняет свой размер под размер компонентов (`VerticalLayoutGroup`+`ContentSizeFilter`), и по идее при изминении текста, в частности его розмера, должна менять под него размер. Но проблема в том, что сам `GameObject` с `Text`ом размера под текст не меняет.
Если в параметре `Vertical Overflow` поставить значение `Overflow` то проблему это не решит, текст что не поместился просто будет отображатся, но это не изменит размер `GameObject`а. Пробывал добавлять `ContentSizeFilter` на объект, что частично решило проблему ведь объект меняет размер. Но при добавлении текста мне требуется добавлять его вниз, а этот компонент не меняет середину `GameObject`, что приводит к смещению объекта вверх.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я конечно не уверен, что вы не читали документацию. Но все же, попробуйте сделать всё по документации. Если вы читали документацию и делали всё по инструкции и я вам сейчас скидываю то, что вы уже пробовали, то извините. https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-UIFitContentSize.html

Comment: Да, проблема была в расположении точки опоры (pivot), так как она по дэфолту располагалась по средине обьекта, он расширялся равномерно. Спасибо.